# OpenGL binding order between EBO and VAO

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, vertex, glad

I`m trying to create opengl triangle and I bumped up with some problem.

EBO : ElementArrayBufferObject
VAO : VertexArrayObject

While I'm trying to bind the EBO before binding the VAO it causes an error and I don't know why.

my code :

```
// Generate the VAO and VBO with only 1 object each
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Make the VAO the current Vertex Array Object by binding it
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
```

It causing problem while rendering.

and if i fix the code like this order.

```
// Generate the VAO and VBO with only 1 object each
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

// Make the VAO the current Vertex Array Object by binding it
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

it`s working as i expected.

I really don`t know why not working binding EBO before VAO.

Answer (score 7):

The [index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) binding is stored within the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers). When `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)` is called the element buffer object is stored in the currently bound Vertex Array Object. Therefore the VAO must be bound before the element buffer with `glBindVertexArray(VAO)`.

Note that compared to the [index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`), the [vertex buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) binding (`ARRAY_BUFFER`) is a global state.
Each attribute which is stated in the VAOs state vector may refer to a different `ARRAY_BUFFER`. This reference is stored when [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called. Then the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER`, is associated to the specified attribute index and the name (value) of the object is stored in the state vector of the currently bound VAO.
However the index buffer is a state of the VAO. If a buffer is bound to the target `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, this buffer is assigned to the currently bound Vertex Array Object.